# Is there a way to find if JProperty types are the same?

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, json.net

My environment is .NET Core 3.1 and I'm using the Newtonsoft.JSON nuget package.

I am creating custom data types using JObject based on a JSON and those data types will be used in other parts of the app. After the data type is created, I can also edit that JSON to generate a different data type and I will add an `IsOutdated` flag so wherever this data type is used, it becomes invalid.

What I want is that whenever someone saves that JSON, if the properties have the same value **types**, the `IsOutdated` won't be set to true. So only if they change the values, nothing will happen. Only if they add/remove properties or change the value types, `IsOutdated` will be true.

I am already using `JToken.DeepEquals` to verify if the existing JSON is the same with the new one, but this also checks the value, not only the type. I want something similar that checks only the type of the JSON properties.

So if I have this:

```
{
   "Id": 1,
   "Obj1":
    {
       "Obj2":
       {
          "Name": "Ed",
          "IsYoung": true
       }
    }
}
```

And I send this:

```
{
   "Id": 1,
   "Obj1":
    {
       "Obj2":
       {
          "Name": "Ed",
          "IsYoung": false
       }
    }
}
```

I don't want the `IsOutdated` flag to change in this case. Because the `IsYoung` property will have the same type.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948395/how-do-i-compare-two-json-ignoring-certain-keys-in-c) help you?

Comment: Use [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/ValidatingJson.htm) to validate the types

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't help me since we don't have specific classes for the payload. We just have JObject.
We can't use JSchema since we don't know beforehand what types the properties should be. And we don't receive a JSON that includes the schema types. We just have a normal JSON and we must compare it to another JSON but only the types, not values.